# How to get the new NavigationView to play nice with status bar scrim?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I've been playing with Google's new design support library and it's a blast! I'm just a little stumped though on the navigation view. All the things I read say that the `NavigationView` is smart enough to handle transparent scrim on its own. (The [android-developers](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) post, for one; search for scrim). Anyway, when I tried to do it I get the following result:

[image: Transparent Scrim]

Which is great; Exactly what I want. Except for one thing. When the drawer is closed, the scrim is an ugly dark grey, not my primaryColorDark . . .

[image]

Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="com.gmail.rixx.justin.envelopebudget.HomeFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The Activity code:

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private Context mContext = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        setUpToolbar();
        setUpNavDrawer();

        findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(mContext, NewTransactionActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }
    }

    private void setUpNavDrawer() {
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)     findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And v21/styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

I modeled after Chris Banes's CheeseSquare app on [github](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) but I'm not getting the behavior I want.

I've tried removing the `windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` and `statusBarColor` from v21/styles, and I get the proper color, but the status bar never goes transparent:

[image]

Help would be appreciated. This is new stuff, So I know we're all learning.

Thanks for reading!

-Justin

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After struggling with this for several more hours, and copiously comparing my code to the cheesesquare app, I found the following: The `DrawerLayout` must have the attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, and the `NavigationView` as well, but the `CoordinatorLayout` should not. Once I made those changes, it worked.

Thanks all, and hopefully this is helpful to somebody!

You can look at my code for the layout [here](https://github.com/justinrixx/Envelope-Budget/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_home.xml).

-Justin

Comment: yesss!!!! thank you thank you. I've been looking for this for hours. The documentation for the support and support design libraries are so hard to find. I find a lot of android stuff is poorly documented.

Comment: I think this could have an unwanted downside: if you later want one of your fragments to go into immersive/full-screen mode, it will be limited by the fact that the Activity-level DrawerLayout is set to size itself as if the status bar and navigation bar are visible.

Answer (score 14):

set this to your navigationView `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`

Comment: I tested on Nougat, it runs well for 2 cases: android:fitsSystemWindows="true/false". but on Kitkat, it should set android:fitsSystemWindows="false" for NavigationView to overlap the status bar

Answer (score 1):

You **should check** newer *SDK examples.*

actually they are using `Coordinatorlayout` in `activity` that you want to draw under `statusbar` and have different theme for that layout, because if you put transparent `statusbar` for other activities where you don't have root layout `Coordinatorlayout` it will show white uncolored `statusbar`.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, I suggest you to see newer drawer example. 

Download new SDK samples and just see how it does. Personally I don't like their solution too, because it's looks like a hack, but it's way better than my current answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

set this to your `navigationView` `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` this will ensure that the navigation will be behind the **`statusbar`** and add `colorAccent` to your **style** in **values** folder.

Answer (score 0):

In your style file try to use **AppCompact** theme as parent ...

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
```

I hope it helps you..